# what codes in activity .kt file example below should i add or change to migrate it to viewBinding from synthetic

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, mobile

I'm trying to migrate to viewbinding from synthetic and want to know the exact code modification i need in the Activity file below.

In my build.gradle(app) i have removed "apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'" and enabled viewBinding (viewBinding true}.

In my activity kt files i also removed synthetic import reference lines. For example

when i remove "import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_kulakan.rv_list"  in the AddOrderActivity.kt below, I get the error "Unresolved reference: rv_list" if i try to build.

```
    private fun renderView() {
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        rv_list.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rv_list.adapter = adapter
```

This is the entire file AddOrderActivity.kt

```
package id.platinum.android.feature.addOrder.main

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.CalendarDay
import id.platinum.android.R
import id.platinum.android.base.BaseActivity
import id.platinum.android.feature.choose.addProduct.ActivitySubCategory
import id.platinum.android.feature.choose.productAdd.ChooseProductActivity
import id.platinum.android.feature.dialog.CartCountDialog
import id.platinum.android.feature.dialog.NoteDialog
import id.platinum.android.feature.dialog.SingleDateDialog
import id.platinum.android.feature.scan.ScanCodeActivity
import id.platinum.android.feature.transaction.successadd.SuccessAddActivity
import id.platinum.android.models.cart.Cart
import id.platinum.android.models.product.Product
import id.platinum.android.rest.entity.RestException
import id.platinum.android.ui.ext.toast
import id.platinum.android.utils.AppConstant
import id.platinum.android.utils.AppSession
import id.platinum.android.utils.Helper
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate


class AddOrderActivity : BaseActivity<AddOrderPresenter, AddOrderContract.View>(),
    AddOrderContract.View,
    SingleDateDialog.Listener, CartCountDialog.Listener,NoteDialog.Listener {

    companion object { var data = "" }


    private val codeOpenScan = 1001
    private val codeOpenChooseProduct = 1002

    private val adapter = AddOrderAdapter()

    override fun createPresenter(): AddOrderPresenter {
        return AddOrderPresenter(this, this)
    }

    override fun createLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_add_order
    }

    override fun startingUpActivity(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        renderView()
        getPresenter()?.onViewCreated()
        openChooseProduct()
    }

    private fun setupToolbar() {
        supportActionBar?.apply {
            setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
            title = getString(R.string.new_add_order)
            elevation = 0f
        }

    }

    private fun renderView() {
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        rv_list.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rv_list.adapter = adapter

        val invoice = getIntent().getStringExtra("invoice")

        adapter.callback = object : AddOrderAdapter.ItemClickCallback {
            override fun onCountDialog(data: Cart, position: Int) {
                openCountDialog(data, position)
            }

            override fun onNote(data: Cart, position: Int) {
                openNoteDialog(data,position)
            }

            override fun onDecrease(data: Cart, position: Int) {
                getPresenter()?.decreaseCart(data, position)
            }

            override fun onIncrease(data: Cart, position: Int) {
                getPresenter()?.increaseCart(data, position)
            }

            override fun onDelete(data: Cart, position: Int) {
                getPresenter()?.deleteCart(data, position)

            }


        }

        rg_payment.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, p1 ->
            when (p1) {
                R.id.rb_tunai -> showTunaiView()
                R.id.rb_piutang -> showPiutangView()
            }
        }

        rg_payment.check(R.id.rb_tunai)


        btn_date.setOnClickListener {
            openSingleDatePickerDialog(getPresenter()?.getSelectedDate())
        }

        btn_bayar.setOnClickListener {
            showLoadingDialog()
            when (rg_payment.checkedRadioButtonId) {
                R.id.rb_tunai -> {
                    getPresenter()?.checkTunai()
                }
                R.id.rb_piutang -> {
                    getPresenter()?.checkPiutang()
                }
            }
        }



//        Log.d("no_invoice", invoice)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_scan_search, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item?.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> finish()
            R.id.action_search -> openChooseProduct()
            R.id.action_scan -> getPresenter()?.onCheckScan()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item!!)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        setupToolbar()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        getPresenter()?.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun showMessage(code: Int, msg: String?) {
        hideLoadingDialog()
        when (code) {
            RestException.CODE_USER_NOT_FOUND -> restartLoginActivity()
            RestException.CODE_MAINTENANCE -> openMaintenanceActivity()
            RestException.CODE_UPDATE_APP -> openUpdateActivity()
            else -> {
                msg?.let {
                    toast(this, it)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun openScanPage() {
        val intent = Intent(this, ScanCodeActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, codeOpenScan)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        openChooseProduct()
    }
    //passing to new Product
    override fun openChooseProduct() {
        val intent = if(data.isEmpty()) Intent(this, ChooseProductActivity::class.java)
        else Intent(this, ActivitySubCategory::class.java).putExtra("data", data)
        startActivityForResult(intent, codeOpenChooseProduct)
    }

    fun openChooseProductData() {
        val intent = Intent(this, ChooseProductActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, codeOpenChooseProduct)
    }

    override fun openNoteDialog(selected: Cart, pos: Int) {
        val noteDialog = NoteDialog.newInstance()
        noteDialog.setData(selected,pos)
        noteDialog.show(this.supportFragmentManager, NoteDialog.TAG)
    }

    override fun getTotalValue(): Double {
        val appSession = AppSession()
        val currency = appSession.getCurrency(this)!!
        val value = tv_total.text.toString().replace(AppConstant.CURRENCY.getCurrencyData(), "").replace(".", "")
        if (value.isBlank() || value.isEmpty()) {
            return 0.0
        }
        return value.toDouble()

    }

    override fun getInVoice(): String? {
        val invoice = getIntent().getStringExtra("invoice")
        return invoice
    }

    override fun showContentView() {
        ll_content.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        ll_error.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun showErrorView(err: String) {
        ll_content.visibility = View.GONE
        ll_error.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        tv_error.text = err
    }

    override fun openSuccessPage(id: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, SuccessAddActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(AppConstant.DATA,id)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

    override fun setCartText(nominal: String) {
        tv_total.text = nominal
        tv_subtotal.text = nominal
    }

    override fun addCart(data: Cart) {
        adapter.addItem(data)
    }

    override fun updateCart(cart: Cart, position: Int) {
        adapter.updateItem(cart, position)
    }

    override fun deleteCart(position: Int) {
        adapter.deleteItem(position)
    }

    override fun showTunaiView() {
        ll_hutang.visibility = View.GONE
    }


    override fun showPiutangView() {
        ll_hutang.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }



    override fun openSingleDatePickerDialog(selected: CalendarDay?) {
        val dateDialog = SingleDateDialog.newInstance()
        val now = LocalDate.now()
        dateDialog.setData(selected, now, null, -1)
        dateDialog.show(this.supportFragmentManager, SingleDateDialog.TAG)
    }

    override fun openCountDialog(selected: Cart, pos: Int) {
        val dialog = CartCountDialog.newInstance()
        dialog.setData(selected, pos, false)
        dialog.show(this.supportFragmentManager, CartCountDialog.TAG)
    }

    override fun onNoteSaved(selected: Cart, pos: Int) {
        getPresenter()?.updateCart(selected,pos)
    }


    override fun onDateClicked(selected: CalendarDay?, type: Int) {
        getPresenter()?.setSelectedDate(selected)
        if (selected == null) {
            et_date.text = ""
        } else {
            et_date.text =
                Helper.getDateFormat(this, selected.date.toString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd MMMM yyyy")
        }
    }

    override fun onCountSaved(selected: Cart, pos: Int) {
        getPresenter()?.updateCart(selected, pos)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == codeOpenScan && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val code = data?.getStringExtra(AppConstant.DATA)
            if (!code.isNullOrBlank() && !code.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                showLoadingDialog()
                getPresenter()?.searchByBarcode(code)
            }

        } else if (requestCode == codeOpenChooseProduct && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                toast(this, "Data not found")
                return
            }
            if (data.getSerializableExtra(AppConstant.DATA) == null) {
                toast(this, "Data not found")
                return
            }
            val product = data.getSerializableExtra(AppConstant.DATA) as Product
            if (product.id_product == null) {
                toast(this, "Data not found")
            } else {
                getPresenter()?.checkCart(product)
            }
        }
    }



}
```

I want to know what codes to add or change in my activities and fragment files using viewBinding

Comment: What have you attempted so far? are we supposed to just rewrite that to use view binding for you?

Comment: i am newbie and just need direction. i read the viewBinding codes are auto generated but dont know where to find them or implement. i gave one specific example so that if i get help on it i can figure the rest.

Answer (score 0):

as given in [this example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities) you'll need to create a binding variable (to reference the views from your XML layout)

it might look something like this

```kotlin
class AddOrderActivity : BaseActivity<AddOrderPresenter, AddOrderContract.View>(),
    AddOrderContract.View,
    SingleDateDialog.Listener, CartCountDialog.Listener,NoteDialog.Listener {

    companion object { var data = "" }

    private lateinit var binding: AddOrderActivityBinding

    private val codeOpenScan = 1001
    private val codeOpenChooseProduct = 1002

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = AddOrderActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
    ...
```

also, the"AddOrderActivityBinding" is a generated class and then name might be a bit different, but it will contain either your class or layout name and "Binding" At the end (so please keep that in mind)

then to replace all of the synthetic you need to basically find all "unresolved references" in your code (like the "Unresolved reference: rv_list" and replace that with binding.rv_list (but the view HAS to have a ID, otherwise you won't be able to reference that through the binding variable))